# How to get renderDataTable to update after user input?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have created a Shiny app that takes a large dataframe and should filter based on certain columns. This dataset has a multitude of columns which I would like to do a checkbox input for a subset group of those columns as written in my code below. The goal for this is to take a user input of the selected columns you can sort from and it should return a customized dataset to the user's input. For example, in the season column, I would want the user to select multiple seasons (2022, 2023) and filter to rows in the dataframe that are in 2022 or 2023.

I have currently tried to use the observeEvent and reactive functions that should produce the output table in my server code. Are there any recommendations how I could fix this?

Below is the code I have worked on:

server.r

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  #title name
  titlePanel("Basic DataTable"),
  
  #row 2: date range, season
  fluidRow(
    #create a date range
    column(6,
           dropdownButton("Dates:", status="default", 
                          width=80, checkboxGroupInput("dates", "Dates:", 
                                                       choices = unique(df$game_date), inline = TRUE))
    ),
    #dropdown for season
    column(6,
           dropdownButton("Season:", status="default", 
                          width=80, checkboxGroupInput("sea", "Season:", 
                                                       choices = c("All", unique(df$season)), inline = TRUE))
    )
  ),
    # Create a new row for the table.
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  ))
```

ui.r

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #row 2
  #date
  dates <- reactive({
    req(input$dates)
    filter(df, game_date == input$dates) 
  })
  observeEvent(dates(), {
    choices <- unique(dates()$dates)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "dates", choices=choices)
  })
  #season
  sea <- reactive({
    req(input$sea)
    filter(df, season == input$sea)
  })
  observeEvent(sea(), {
    choices <- unique(sea()$sea)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "sea", choices=choices)
  })
  
    
  
  # choose columns to display
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$dates)
    dates() %>% filter(game_date == input$dates)
    req(input$sea)
    sea() %>% filter(season == input$sea)

    df
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: without df we can't test! So `dput(df)`.

Comment: Well, your `renderDataTable` returns the unfiltered dataset `df`. To render the filtered dataset try with `df %>% filter(season %in% input$sea, game_date %in% input$dates)` in `DT::renderDataTable`.